# form not saving data in db

Tags: django, django-forms

i'm creating a form for product create and i have 5 image fields in product model ,user can upload 5 or 0 images as per requirement , but form is not saving data
`python`

## models.py

```
class Category(models.Model):
    cate_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=45)
    product_description = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    product_category_fk = models.ForeignKey('Category', on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_column='product_category_fk',related_name='pros')
    image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to='chand_imgs',blank=True)
    image2 = models.ImageField(upload_to='chand_imgs',blank=True)
    image3 = models.ImageField(upload_to='chand_imgs',blank=True)
    image4 = models.ImageField(upload_to='chand_imgs',blank=True)
    image5 = models.ImageField(upload_to='chand_imgs',blank=True)
    
#forms.py
class CategoryForm(forms.ModelForm):
    category_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('category_name', )
    
class ProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta():
     model  = Product
     fields = ('product_category_fk','product_name','product_description','price','quantity','image1','image2','image3','image4','image5',)
    
#views.py
@login_required
def product_management(request):
    form = ProductForm(data=request.POST)
      if request.method =='POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            post=form.save(commit=True)
            if 'picture' in request.FILES:
                form.picture =request.FILES['picture']
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))  
        else:
             return render(request,'chandler/index.html',{'form':form})     
    else:
        form = ProductForm()
        return render(request,'chandler/product.html',{'form':form})

#product.html
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<form method=”post” enctype=”multipart/form-data” action="" >
    <h2>New post</h2>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
<button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
{% else %}
    <h2>Please login first!!!!</h2>
{% endif %}
```

form not saving any data i know my view is incorrect ,already tried different methods

Comment: `method=”post” enctype=”multipart/form-data”` - make sure that these quotes are `straight` ones and not `curly`

Comment: @art06 did the trick ;_;

Answer (score 0):

change

`<form method=”post” enctype=”multipart/form-data” action="" >`

to

`<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="" >`